# How to bind files from a dynamic folder in an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm making a Windows Phone 8.1 app. I know how to bind data from a folder with selected data, but my folder changes data continuously. My question is: how can I add the data automatically when they are added in the folder without having to modify the code?

In this moment my code is:

```
ObservableCollection<LongListData> listData = new ObservableCollection<LongListData>();

listData.Add(new LongListData() { ImgText = "Image1", ImgUrl = new Uri("Images/1.jpg", UriKind.Relative) });
listData.Add(new LongListData() { ImgText = "Image2", ImgUrl = new Uri("Images/2.jpg", UriKind.Relative) });
listData.Add(new LongListData() { ImgText = "Image3", ImgUrl = new Uri("Images/3.jpg", UriKind.Relative) });
listData.Add(new LongListData() { ImgText = "Image4", ImgUrl = new Uri("Images/4.jpg", UriKind.Relative) });

MainLongListSelector.ItemsSource = listData;
```

With this code, I can add images in the ListData. If I add an image in the folder, I could add another command "listData.Add(new LongListData()...". 
My question is: is there a code that adds the Images in the ListData automatically every time that the contents of the folder changes? 
I think there may be a code with a loop that adds all files in the folder, but I don't know how to build it.

Comment: Please add a coding example of what you are trying to do

Comment: That's not how binding works.  Step back and research that.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) for the given directory, and update the `ObservableCollection` whenever the files in the directory change...

Important: The FileSystemWatcher's event may not be called on the UI thread, so you have to dispatch it to the UI thread...